# How to fix "Missing Constraint: Import-Package:" and "Require-Bundle" in Eclipse RCP

Tags: java, eclipse, dependencies, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I am developing an Eclipse RCP application. Therefore I am trying to implement an ISelectionListener. Therefore I have to import the package "org.eclipse.ui". When i wanted to import the package the error that I have add the package to my project. When I did this an then want to start my Application an Errorwindow like the folowing appears: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVTAO.png (Sorry my reputation is to low to post some images)

In my case it contains more items but all with the error: "Missing Constraint: Import-Package" or "Required-Bundle". I was trying to add the packages to my manifest file as explained in the error but this does not change anything.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You have to the package in plugin.xml file in dependency section.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i was trying this but it doesn't work. It had the same effect as putting it to the manifest.

Comment: If you want , you can refresh the project so that error will disappear.

Comment: Thanks again, but when i refresh the project and start it again after the same error pops up

Comment: The validation is saying the `org.apache.xmlrpc` plug-in requires the `javax.xml.bind` plug-in. In the Run > Run Configurations dialog find your RCP in the Eclipse Applications section and use 'Add Required Plug-ins' to try and get a consistent set.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, when i go to this dialog there are about 600 plug-ins which are included and when i press on the buttun no new plug-ins appear and on the next start the same error appears again.

Comment: I'm facing the exact same problem right now. "Missing contraint: Require-Bundle"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error you have is about inconsistent set of "Plug-ins" selected for Run/Debug configuration.

By default you are running with "all workspace and enabled target plug-ins" that may be not an optimal choice for RCP development. You can try to change it to "plug-ins selected below only" and then tune it manually.

For example you can uncheck everything except plug-ins that declare the product and the application and then use "Add Required Plug-ins" button.

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem. In addition I have to say that I have to check only the project I want to run before clicking the "Add required plug-ins" button.